# Programmatically created window does not show up as correct size

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This is my code in the applicationDidFinishLaunching function,

```
    // Create window
NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 300)
    styleMask:(NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask)
                                                      backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

//Create gl view
NSRect frame = [window contentRectForFrameRect:[window frame]];
MyOpenGLView *glView = [[MyOpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

[window setContentView:glView];
[window makeFirstResponder:glView];

// Show up
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

The application builds and runs. But when it runs, the window *seems* to be full screen. In other words, I get the name of the application on the top left and nothing else on screen changes. Its like an empty window the size of my screen. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Additional information: initWithFrame function in MyOpenGLView class,

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
[self myInit];
return self;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess you're using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) and not manual reference counting. To review, here's your code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:
    NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 300) styleMask:(NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask |
 NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask)
                     backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

    //Create gl view
    NSRect frame = [window contentRectForFrameRect:[window frame]];
    MyOpenGLView *glView = [[MyOpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [window setContentView:glView];
    [window makeFirstResponder:glView];

    // Show up
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

}
```

Under ARC, the `NSWindow` you create here in this method only lasts as long as the method. In other words, it will be created, shown for a split second (if even at all) and then will immediately be deallocated and removed from the screen. In order to make it persist, you should define it as an instance variable. For example:

MDAppController.h:

```
  @interface MDAppController : NSObject

  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSWindow *window;

  @end
```

MDAppController.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {

     self.window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:
                      NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 300)
                   styleMask:(NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask |
            NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask)
                     backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
   // or 
   // _window = ....

   // ....
   // Show up
   [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
   // or 
   // [_window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

Here, you're setting the instance variable `window` to the `NSWindow` you create and since that ivar is defined as strong, it will persist after that method returns.

Comment: Why do you write `self.window=...` instead of just `window=...` and the same when showing it as well? I do understand your point about ARC  acting and deleting it because it thinks I don't need it anymore.

Comment: @ChromoZoneX: well, by default, the automatically `@synthesize`'d ivar for `window` would be named `_window` with a leading underscore. You could directly access the ivar in code by using `_window`, like I've shown in the updated example. In this case it likely wouldn't matter which method you use....